# How do you answer the following question when someone asks: 我想认识一个美国朋友，你给我介绍一下，可以吗？

Tags: mandarin, simplified-characters, names, introductions

```
我想认识一个美国朋友，你给我介绍一下，可以吗？
```

My Chinese teacher asked me the question above ^. Am I supposed to say:

```
这是我的中国老师, 王朋.
```

or

```
这是我的美国朋友, Rodger Smith.
```

Basically, should I be introducing my Chinese teacher who asked the question to my American friend, or should I introduce my American friend to my Chinese teacher?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depend on who you are speaking to. If you are speaking to your teacher, "这是我的美国朋友, Rodger Smith" is correct; If you are speaking to your friend, "这是我的中国老师, 王朋." is correct. But neither is the answer to the question.

The question is "我想认识一个美国朋友，你给我介绍一下，**可以吗**？". Your immediate answer should be something like "當然可以 (of course, I can)". If you want to answer more detailedly, you can add "我明天就给你介绍一个美国朋友"

Then you can go get your friend and introduce them to each other

"Rodger, 这是我的中国老师, 王朋."

"老师, 这是我的美国朋友, Rodger Smith."

Comment: 谢谢 谢谢 谢谢 谢谢 谢谢 谢谢